# How to produce cartesian square in jq?

Tags: jq, cartesian-product

How to produce the Cartesian square of an array in `jq`?

Input:

```
[0,1,2]
```

Output:

```
[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],
 [1,0],[1,1],[1,2],
 [2,0],[2,1],[2,2]]
```

I found simple way to make it work with arithmetic operations, but no luck with comma operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cartesian product

One way to generate the array of pairs in the specified order would be as follow:

```
def data: [0,1,2];

data | [.[] as $i | .[] as $j | [$i, $j] ]
```

Alternatively, avoiding $-variables:

```
[range(0;3) | [.] + (range(0;3)|[.])]
```

### Square matrix with m[i][j] = [i,j]

```
def Mij(n):
  [ range(0;n) as $i
    | [ range(0;n) as $j
        | [$i, $j] ] ];


Mij(3)
```

produces:

```
[[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2]],[[1,0],[1,1],[1,2]],[[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]]]
```

Comment: I believe you have one excess depth level. Something like `[.[] as $i | .[] as $j | [$i, $j]]` would work.